# How to catch "JavaScript heap out of memory"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm caching some things in the system memory. I don't need to cache everything but I do want to utilize the ram as much as possible.

Is there a way to tell if the next action, whatever it may be would crash the VM?

JS `try/catch` fails here, `v8.getHeapStatistics` doesn't really help since despite storing maybe just a single Number, `v8` might want to reallocate the entire array and request an allocation several orders of magnitude bigger than the data I've got at hand and I've got no control over that.

I can't believe that there is no reliable way to utilize system memory in `node.js`, that would be incredibly dumb.

Comment: you can use  --max-old-space-size flag to set how much ram/memory your program should use like `node  --max-old-space-size=<size in MB eg: 1024> <yourFileName>.js`. By default it uses 512 MB

Comment: @saketh that just moves the limit though, I still don't have any idea whether I'm about to run out or not

Comment: I believe This error occurs when the memory allocated for the execution application is less than the required memory when run application. So you can set max out memory and if your application really needs that it can use if not the memory can be used by other programs

Comment: have you tried `process.MemoryUsage()` it will tell how much memory/heapUsed

Comment: @saketh its the same as v8.getHeapStatistics

Comment: looks like yes but I m not completely sure and v8.getHeapStatistics seems to have more stats. Have you tried setting the flag to max memory of your system and see if you are still getting the heap out of memory error

Comment: @saketh its not about getting it to run on one system but creating a package that can adjust to any server. I can make do with as little as 1kB but the more memory I can use the faster it goes.

Comment: Can't really do what you're asking in a garbage collected system and in a system with object implementations that aren't entirely known.  There's just way too much allocation and freeing happening behind the scenes and out of phase with when your code runs.  In V8, even an array and a plain object have different storage formats depending upon how they are being used.  I would suggest picking your own internal measures (numbers of objects, your own calculation of size of the objects, etc...) for how much to put in your cache that, with testing, keeps you in a safe memory usage range.

Comment: This might be useful: https://medium.com/@evgeni.leonti/detect-heap-overflow-on-node-js-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-41cb649c6b33